# Data is not updating in the chaincode

Tags: blockchain, javascript, private-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

This is my HTML form

```
<div class="text-center form-container">
        <form id="updateForm" action="" name="updateOwner" style="display: none;">
            <h3>Bid for the company</h3>
            <div>
                <label for="bidLicenseNo">License Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="bidLicenseNo" name="licenseNo" required />
            </div>            
            
            <div>
                <label for="bidAmount">Bid Amount:</label>
                <input type="number" id="bidAmount" name="owner" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="bidderNID">Your NID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="bidderNID" name="bidderNID" required />
            </div>
    
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Place Bid</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
// UPDATE: CHANGING CAR OWNER
        const updateForm = document.getElementById('updateForm')

                // Update form submission event
             updateForm.addEventListener("submit", async function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const licenseNo = document.getElementById('bidLicenseNo').value;
            const bidAmount = document.getElementById('bidAmount').value;
            const bidderNID = document.getElementById('bidderNID').value;

            const bodyParam = new URLSearchParams({
                licenseNo: licenseNo,
                bidAmount: bidAmount,
                bidderNID: bidderNID
            });

            try {
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/givenBid', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: bodyParam
                });

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const result = await response.json();
                    alert(result.message);
                    getAll();
                } else {
                    alert('Unable to update');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                alert('Failed to load data!');
            }
        });
</script>
```

I am calling it from here

```
// change car owner
app.post('/givenBid', function (req, res) {
    givenBid.main( req.body  )
    .then(result => {
        res.send({message: 'Updated successfully'})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error({ err })
        res.send('FAILED TO LOAD DATA!')
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running at port 3000'))
```

My chaincode function is this

```
async givenBid(ctx, companyLicense, newBidAmount, bidderNID) {
        console.info('============= START : givenBid ===========');
        
        console.log('License Number:', companyLicense);
        
        const companyAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getState(companyLicense);
        if (!companyAsBytes || companyAsBytes.length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`${companyLicense},${typeof(companyLicense)},${companyAsBytes.toString()} does not exist`);
        }
    
        const company = JSON.parse(companyAsBytes.toString());
    
        if (bidderNID === company.ownerNID) {
            throw new Error("Owner cannot bid in their own company");
        }
    
        if (newBidAmount > company.currentBiddingAmount) {
            if (newBidAmount > company.minimumBiddingAmount) {
                company.currentBiddingAmount = newBidAmount;
                company.highestBidderNID = bidderNID;
                company.remainingBids--;
    
                await ctx.stub.putState(companyLicense, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(company)));
                console.info('============= END : givenBid ===========');
            } else {
                throw new Error("New bid amount must be greater than the minimum bidding amount");
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error("New bid amount must be higher than the previous highest bid amount");
        }
    }
```

**The chaincode is working but it shows 1234 does not exist. I have checked the both of their type which is string and I manually stored the licence number 1234. its also present. Whats wrong in this code. I am a beginner please help**